# Querying foreign keys different results

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreign-keys

I am writing some code that will disable and enable foreign keys on a table. It appears to run fine.  When I check the status of the Foreign key immediately executing the code the status appears to be unchanged with one query and changed with a different query.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is and was hoping someone can help me out and explain this anomaly and or suggest a fix to my code.

Below is my test CASE along with sample data to show what I have done.

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Faith', 'Mazzarone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Saladino' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Micheal', 'Palmice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Joseph', 'Zaza' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Jerry', 'Torchiano' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE items 
(PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Black Shoes', 79.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Brown Pants', 111.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'White Shirt', 10.99 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE items 
ADD CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id);

create table purchases(
  ORDER_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  customer_id   number, 
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER, 
  QUANTITY NUMBER, 
  purchase_date timestamp
);

insert  into purchases (customer_id, product_id, quantity, purchase_date) 
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-22 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL 
select 1, 101,3, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 12
union all
select 2, 101,2, date '2023-01-15' + level * interval '8' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 2, 102,2,date '2023-04-13' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 3, 101,2, date '2023-02-01' + level * interval '1 05:03' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 10
union all
select 3, 101,1, date '2023-04-22' + level * interval '23' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 23
union all
select 3, 100,1,  date '2022-03-01' + level * interval '1 00:23:05' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 4, 102,1, date '2023-01-01' + level * interval '5' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 60;

ALTER TABLE purchases 
ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT customers_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT items_fk FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES items(product_id);

/* both queries fine here */

SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name,
                b.status
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND b.status = 'ENABLED'
            ORDER BY 1

FULL_TABLE_NAME
    CONSTRAINT_NAME STATUS
"XXX"."PURCHASES"   ITEMS_FK    ENABLED
"XXX"."PURCHASES"   CUSTOMERS_FK    ENABLED

select owner, table_name, r_constraint_name, status
 from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'R';

OWNER   TABLE_NAME  R_CONSTRAINT_NAME   STATUS
XXX PURCHASES   CUSTOMERS_PK    ENABLED
XXX PURCHASES   ITEMS_PK    ENABLED

/* disable foreign keys */

BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND b.status = 'ENABLED'
            ORDER BY 1 )  LOOP
            
        dbms_output.put_line ( 'Disable the constraint ' || r.constraint_name ||' (on table ' || r.full_table_name || ')' ) ;
        dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement ( 'alter table ' || r.full_table_name || ' disable constraint ' || r.constraint_name ) ;
        
    END LOOP ;
END ;
/

Statement processed.
Disable the constraint ITEMS_FK (on table "XXX"."PURCHASES")
Disable the constraint CUSTOMERS_FK (on table "XXX"."PURCHASES")

/* status different between queries ????. Problem here!!!
*/

SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name,
                b.status
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND b.status = 'ENABLED'
            ORDER BY 1

FULL_TABLE_NAME
    CONSTRAINT_NAME STATUS
"XXX"."PURCHASES"   ITEMS_FK    ENABLED
"XXX"."PURCHASES"   CUSTOMERS_FK    ENABLED

select owner, table_name, r_constraint_name, status
 from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'R';

OWNER   TABLE_NAME  R_CONSTRAINT_NAME   STATUS
XXX PURCHASES   CUSTOMERS_PK    DISABLED
XXX PURCHASES   ITEMS_PK    DISABLED
```

Comment: You are looking for the status of the referenced constraint, that is enabled `b.status from ... a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name`

Comment: @astentx how do  I find the constraint that was disabled. In addition, I have code that enables the FK (undo what was done) then I would need to look for the enable constraint

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 2 different queries and they are correctly showing the results.
you're assuming that you are seeing the status of the foreign key constraint but... that is not the case. Add some additional columns to the query and it all becomes clear.

```
SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name,
                a.status,
                b.constraint_name, 
                b.table_name, 
                b.status
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND b.status = 'ENABLED'
            ORDER BY 1;

"ACDC"."PURCHASES"  ITEMS_FK      DISABLED  ITEMS_PK        ITEMS       ENABLED
"ACDC"."PURCHASES"  CUSTOMERS_FK. DISABLED  CUSTOMERS_PK    CUSTOMERS   ENABLED
```

The column `b.status` is the status of the *referenced constraint*, not the status of the foreign key constraint. The referenced constraint is the primary key value of the 2 tables and the status is "enabled" since you didn't touch those....

To find referenced constraints, just use that other query you are showing

```
select owner, table_name, r_constraint_name, status
 from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'R';
```

But... I would not take this route. What if there is a constraint that is already disabled before you run your script ? That constraint will then be enabled again by your "enable" script. Much safer to create a table where you store the name of the constraints you have disabled so you know which ones to enable again afterwards.

Comment: Thank you!! Am I correct that referencing a.status in the code would be the correct thing to do?

Comment: That is correct